# Execute bot command

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot. I'm using `"telegram-bot/api": "^2.3"`, laravel 5.7

```
try {
    $bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client('XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXX');

    $bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {
        $answer = 'Добро пожаловать!';
        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer);
    });

    $bot->command('stop', function ($message) use ($bot) {
        $keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            array
            (
                array("to start command")
            ), true);

        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), 'test', null, false, null, $keyboard);
    });

    $bot->run();

} catch (\TelegramBot\Api\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
```

I need to execute /start command when I press on "to start command" button

Thank you